# R: Creating a ggplot2 barchart of timedate y-variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to create an otherwise very simple ggplot barchart of a timedate variable on the y-axis. It plots fine using `geom_point` or `geom_line`, but as soon as I replace those with `geom_bar`, R either crashes or returns me a blank, grey graph.

My raw data is character strings of the format:

```
day       time
1/1/2015  2:30:14
2/1/2015  15:10:40
3/1/2015  8:50:05
```

And knowing that ggplot2 can be a bit picky with time and date classes, I format my variables to POSIXct and Date as follows:

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales)
datetime <- data.frame(date = c("1/1/2015", "2/1/2015", "3/1/2015"), 
                   time = c("2:30:14", "15:10:40", "8:50:05"))
datetime$date <- as.Date(datetime$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
datetime$time <- as.POSIXct(datetime$time, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Then, creating a simple scatter plot of the data works fine:

```
ggplot(datetime, aes(date, time)) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab("Day") +
    ylab("Time") +
    scale_y_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"), 
                     labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

But, replacing `geom_point()` with `geom_bar(stat="identity")` like I normally would to create a barchart seems to result in a everloading process and sometimes a crashing of R:

```
ggplot(datetime, aes(date, time)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    xlab("Day") +
    ylab("Time") +
    scale_y_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"), 
                     labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

I'm probably misunderstanding the functionality of ggplot2, so can someone please enlighten me as to what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Regardless of what you’re doing, R shouldn’t crash. This sounds like a bug.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the "error" but all I get is "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale", for both the geom_point and the geom_bar... (Edit: @anders Is there maybe a difference between the "sample dataset" that you gave here and the one you used? Might just be a spelling mistake.)

Comment: @maj Same here. In addition, the days are not parsed correctly, I needed to change the format to `'%m/%d/%Y'`. But once removing the x scale, the R hang can be reproduced.

Comment: I got the same error as @maj, but when I change `scale_x_continuous` to `scale_x_date` (reasonable for date variable) the scatterplot works but the barchart indeed causes r to crash.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated the post to fix the formatting of the day variable - perhaps I made the mockup example a bit too fast. I'll go back and compare it to my own data problem and see why that doesn't give a "discrete value..."-error.

Comment: Ok, like Marta Cz-C noted just before me, the discrete-error comes from the scale_x_continuous term. My problem seems to persist if i just drop that bit though. I'll update the OP to reflect this immediately.

Comment: Can reproduce the problem now. It seems to me that there is an issue with `breaks = date_breaks("1 hour")` - when I leave that out, the result might not make a lot of sense anymore, but at least then there *is* a result. Maybe you should use a different format for your time variable (> just a guess)? Edit: I have noticed that R does not really crash but it just seems to be working hard in the background...

Comment: Yes, you're right. From Marta Cz-C's explanation below, R is just really busy calculating small intervals since 1/1/1970. Adding a ylimit solves the problem.

Comment: Great. If you believe that the issue has been resolved, you should answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ggplot2 the barchart's y-scale by default starts from zero. Or, in case of date and time value, from the start value, which is 1/1/1970. It means that your bars are 45-years long (for time values R apparently sets today as a date). But you force ggplot2 to use very fine scale over this period of time: you set breaks to be one hour:

```
scale_y_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"),
                     labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

which probably cause R to crash.
If you use just

```
ggplot(data, aes(day, time)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

It will work, but the bars will be indistinguishable. To make the bars distinguishable you have to change y-limits, for example to a time period between 0:00:00 to 23:59:59. This works for me:

```
ggplot(data, aes(day, time)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("Day") +
  ylab("Time") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(as.POSIXct("0:0:0", format="%H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("23:59:59", format="%H:%M:%S"))) +
  scale_y_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"),
                 labels = date_format("%H:%M")) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = pretty_breaks(10))
```

Comment: Great explanation. This makes a lot of sense and setting a ylimit with coord_cartesian also solved the problem! Thanks!